# Measurements with multimeter giving paradoxical values

Tags: voltage, measurement

I study civil engineering (majoring in electrical engineering) and part of the program in my university is a design project. For this project my team developed a PCB and naturally it was full of bugs.
This week we were debugging it and we got a few strange values. After applying a voltage we checked a few lines to see if they had logical voltages on them (referenced to the ground). 2 were really strange. Point 1 had 0 voltage between it and the ground, point 2 had 23 V between it and the ground, measuring the voltage between 1 and 2 with the meter resulted in a difference of 0V. How is this possible?

The issue is already resolved. There was a resistor that was not soldered properly, so the point was floating (as in not connected to anything). After connecting it, the multimeter gave expected values.

To reiterate: how can a badly connected circuit cause a multimeter to contradict itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the meter as being a resistor (say 10M ohms) with an ideal meter in parallel.

Imagine now that point 1 is open, point 2 is 23V wrt ground. You will measure 23V wrt ground on pin 2, but *anything* wrt point 1 will measure zero volts, whether that be ground or your 23V (wrt ground) point 2 or anywhere else.

It's not a violation of Kirchoff's law (KVL) because the meter is not ideal and you're not making the measurements simultaneously.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Qpch.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Looking at the above schematic, if VM2 is an ideal meter and VM1 is a real meter (10M ohm input resistance), then when the switch is in the NC position, VM1 reads 0V and VM2 reads 23V. When the switch is in the NO position, VM1 also reads 0V, but VM2 reads 0V.

Comment: Ah, I thought it would have something to do with the non-ideality of the meter. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the question.

> There was a resistor that was not soldered properly, so the point was
>   floating (as in not connected to anything). After connecting it, the
>   multimeter gave expected values.

For a voltmeter to work, there needs to be a current through a large resistor, typically 1M on lower end meters. Since one side of the meter was floating, it was an open circuit, therefore no current flow. Probe any point on your board and leave one probe in the air. The same thing will happen. Nothing magical or paradoxical here...